# React Native Navigation white screen after build

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Im using expo for my app, when I'm using expo emulator all works fine, but when I'm trying to build it, it gives me white screen (I have also added some alerts to find out is it going into component, but it's not)

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {Text, View} from "react-native";
import Test from "./Test.js";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function TestSecond() {
    useEffect(() => {
        alert('testFirst')
    }, [])
    return (
        <Text>test First</Text>
    )
}

export default function TestFirst() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Test" component={Test} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Test2" component={TestSecond}/>
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Im pretty confused what's wrong with this..

Comment: Hi @Paweł can you please share the code of Test from Test.js ? And also remove the `<View style={{flex: 1}}>`

Comment: @darshilsakhiya hello, probably I have spoted the reason why it's not working - I was not importing 'react-native-gesture-handler', when I've added that, suddenly it woked (except one view in routing) - when I will make sure that was the reason, I will put separated answer to this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found out what I was missing, maybe it will help somebody - all I had to do was add `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` on TestFirst component.